# Compressing a file into tar.xz archive using javascript in a web browser

Tags: javascript, compression, tar, lzma, xz

I need to compress a file into tar.xz archive using javascript in a web browser. Is there any workable library to do this work?
That is, I need libraries for TAR and XZ (LZMA2) compressing.
But I've found just https://github.com/nmrugg/LZMA-JS/ and for zip compressing (http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) but not for xz and tar.

**EDIT**
XZ pure js library is here:
https://blog.slava.online/xz-archiver-webworker-for-browser-pure-js/

Comment: Have you looked into [tar-js](https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/tar-js) and [xz-pipe](https://github.com/yetzt/node-xz-pipe)

Comment: @Marcus, Of course.nodejs is unuseful for browser.Anyway,I did it y myself using Emscripten. I think then I will hae a free time I will share my project.